# if single word already output, continue

Tags: php

I'm very new in PHP, and would like to do a foreach loop that won't repeat a result if the same item has been output before.

Here's my code:

```
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        echo ($attachment->post_title);
    }
```

As you can see, the word would be pulled by `echo ($attachment->post_title);`.

Is there a way to do some checking and avoid duplicates?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$outputted = array();

foreach($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
   if (!isset($outputted[$attachment->post_title])) {
      echo $attachment->post_title;
      $outputted[$attachment->post_title] = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just had a thought, an evil one, what if you assigned the value to FALSE instead of TRUE? It would still work here, but it could TOTALLY introduce unexpected behavior.

Comment: doesn't matter what's assigned, as long as something IS assigned. I'm testing for the existence of the key (the post title).

Answer (score 2):

You could use array_unique like Rajesh suggested and not worry with making an extra array.

```
foreach ( array_unique($attachments) as $id => $attachment ) {
        echo ($attachment->post_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {

         if (!isset($outputs[$attachment->post_title])){
            $outputs[$attachment->post_title] = true;
            echo ($attachment->post_title);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$output = array();

foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    if (!isset($output[$attachment->post_title])){
        echo ($attachment->post_title);
        $output[$attachment->post_title] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use associative arrays:

```
$used = array();
foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
    if (!array_key_exists($attachment->post_title, $used)) {
        $used[$attachment->post_title] = 1;
        echo $attachment->post_title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $attachments_posted[] = $attachment;
    if (!array_search($attachment, $attachments_posted))
        echo ($attachment->post_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to keep track of which titles you've already seen:

```
$seen = array();
foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
    if (array_key_exists($attachment->post_title, $seen)) {
        continue;
    }
    $seen[$attachment->post_title] = true;
    echo $attachment->post_title;
}
```